# October CMS create a multi select Form field

Tags: php, html, octobercms

I need to create a multi select form field in October Cms backend form (fields.yaml). I applied the following method

select_field:
     label: Sample
     type: dropdown
     attributes: {multiple:'multiple'}

Options to this field will be invoked from the model

Everything is working good but when i submit the form only the first selected option is being inserted as JSON data in the database table text field. I want every selected option to be stored. I have also declared the field as Jsonable in model  ie., protected $jsonable = ['field_name'];

**Note :** When I use type as **checkboxlist** it is working as I thought but I don't want it to be checkboxlist. I'm new to October cms is there any easy way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use a dropdown field with mutiple value because it was made to handle single value. as the checkbox and radio this is why there are checkboxList(i guess).

But i found a solution. 
Use a partial as field type in fields.yaml instead of dropdown

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-partial

Create a partial with the content below (notice the [] in name attribute this is why it work !)

But be aware that this is just a trick and you **can only use direct yaml options assignment** https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dropdown

```
<?php
    $fieldOptions = $field->options();
    //get the field value as an array
    $selectedValues = (array)$field->value;

?>
<!-- Dropdown -->
<?php if ($this->previewMode): ?>
    <div class="form-control"><?= (isset($fieldOptions[$field->value])) ? e(trans($fieldOptions[$field->value])) : '' ?></div>
<?php else: ?>

    <select
        id="<?= $field->getId() ?>"
        name="<?= $field->getName() ?>[]"
        class="form-control custom-select"
        <?= $field->getAttributes() ?>>
        <?php if ($field->placeholder): ?>
            <option value=""><?= e(trans($field->placeholder)) ?></option>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php foreach ($fieldOptions as $value => $option): ?>
            <?php
                if (!is_array($option)) $option = [$option];
            ?>
            <option

                <?= in_array($value, $selectedValues)  ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                <?php if (isset($option[1])): ?>data-<?=strpos($option[1],'.')?'image':'icon'?>="<?= $option[1] ?>"<?php endif ?>
                value="<?= $value ?>">
                    <?= e(trans($option[0])) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
<?php endif?>
```

And for the yaml

````
```
select_field:
    label: Sample
    type: partial
    path:$/author/plugin/models/classfolder/_my_partial.htm
    attributes: {multiple:'multiple'}
    options:
        key:value
        key:value
```
````

A better approche would be may be to build a widget or make a pull request
if you have the ability you can touch the core and add

the same content in \modules\backend\widgets\form\partials
with name _field_dropdownlist.htm

then in \modules\backend\widgets\form\Form.php line 630
change :

```
$optionModelTypes = ['dropdown', 'radio', 'checkboxlist', 'balloon-selector'];
```

to add your partial name without _field or .htm ex _field_dropdownlist.htm become dropdowList

```
$optionModelTypes = ['dropdown', 'radio', 'checkboxlist', 'balloon-selector','dropdowlist'];
```

now in your yaml file juste use type:dropdownList and it will work.

Comment: I did the same thing as like you did . I've created a partial and set the name attribute of the multi select option as an array and everything works fine But what stopped me to post that answer is that how to display the selected options in the select field of the partial. I'd like to try your second approach that is to build a widget. I hope that it should work and thank you Greg Bee

Comment: Hi, Could you tell me how do I Update a multi select field with empty value.  Incase if the user doen't want to select anything. I'm trying a lot, but I could not able to find a better solution

Comment: i think the best way to do that is by overiding the formBeforeUpdate($model) function within the controller and check if your field was send or not then you could hanlde this case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your interest Greg. As I'm new to October CMS I could not able to easily figure and implement **formBeforeUpdate($model) function within the controller**, During your free time, I request you to share me some example or the outlook of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also daftspunk has propose a workaround: https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/1829#issuecomment-193018469

Answer (score 0):

You can use "taglist" widget to do this ;-)

Comment: FYI, taglist has been added in octobercms only in the latest version not in beta.

Comment: @VijayWilson, yeap, if you don`t have it then you can replace select ui by "repeater + checkbox" or "belongsToMany relation" it can have same functionality but another view

Comment: Yes you are right, but  actually it was a requirement to place a multiselect dropdown.

Comment: I don't get the taglist. It's located in backend/formwidgets/ along all the other widgets but you can't select it via the builder > models?

Comment: Sorry, i can`t find it anymore to 0o

Answer (score 0):

you could use select2 jquery plugin

_widget.htm

```
<!-- for booking table -->
<select  class="form-control" id="sle1" name="Booking[business_car_id]" >

    <?php   foreach($businesscars as $key => $value): ?>
        <option class="form-control" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" >
             <?php
            echo $value; ?>  
        </option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

and put select2.js and select2.css in assets/js and assets/css forlder respectively

download select 2 from here
https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

To handle Many to Many relation through form, you can use multi select input or checkboxes.
In october cms, there are couple [relational form widget](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation) and [taglist form widget](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-taglist) to handle this kind of situations.
In the fields.yaml define the following:

```
# relational form widget
categories: # relationship name  defined in the model
  label: 'Associated categories'
  span: full
  required: 1
  type: relation
  nameFrom: title # db column name to fetch to show the display value

#taglist form widget
  categories:
    label: 'Associated categories'
    span: full
    mode: relation
    required: 1
    type: taglist
    nameFrom: title
```