# How to add multi select value in database in October CMS Backend?

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

[image]

Not inserted multi select value in database.

My fields.yaml Code is :

```
 related_recipe:
        label: 'Related Recipe'
        span: auto
        nameFrom: recipe_title
        descriptionFrom: description
        attributes: {multiple:'multiple'}
        type: relation
```

My model code is :

```
public $belongsTo = [

                    'related_recipe' => [
                         'Qdata\Taeq\Models\Recipe',
                      'conditions' => 'status = 1'
                      ],

                 ];
```

Currently only one selected value inserted in database.need add multiple value in database. Can any one have the solution of it ?

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620124/october-cms-create-a-multi-select-form-field

Comment: @VijayWilson i want to set the data using type = "relation" not partial.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a $belongsToMany relation in this case.

$belongsTo means your model is link with a single entity of your Recipe model.

Comment: I have checked $belongsToMany but not working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do so with relation you need to go with "belongsToMany" relation. for example:
In your Model

`'related_recipes' => [
            'Qdata\Taeq\Models\Recipe',
            'table' => 'pivot_table_name',
            'key' => 'foreign_key_of_pivot_table',
            'otherKey' => 'other_key',
        ],`

In related another Model

`'makers' => [
            'Qdata\Taeq\Models\AnotherModel',
            'table' => 'pivot_table_name',
            'key' => 'foreign_key_of_pivot_table',
            'otherKey' => 'other_key',
        ],`

this will save your multiselect dropdown data in the related pivot table in your database.